# A perfect subset of any complete metric space is uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

A perfect subset of real line is uncountable. Is it true in any complete metric space?

We know that every perfect set in locally compact complete metric space is uncountable. Taking this into consideration the answer is no.

But if we use Baire category theorem then the answer is yes.

What am I lacking? Please help.

Comment: How does your second sentence give "no"?

Comment: every complete metric space need not be locally compact

Comment: But you don't have an if and only if statement...

Comment: got it. thanks.

Comment: Please change your username to something more appropriate, as the new SE policy prohibits [offensive language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233). I would say that something like 'four-twenty' is more acceptable because it does not have the same connotations as writing 420 out as a number.

Comment: Perfect sets in complete metric spaces are uncountable. This is proved as Theorem 6.65 (page 72) in Real and Abstract Analysis by Hewitt and Stromberg.